# How is allowing residual covariances related to changing total score of a scale?

Tags: covariance, residuals, confirmatory-factor

For what reason should I think about changing the total score of a scale if I allowed residual covariances for similar sounding items?
If I still work with all of the items should I think about changing the total score?